# How to put strings under each other and assign a number to it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to reform this

```
A,B                   
AFD,DNGS,SGDH         
NHYG,QHD,lkd,uyete    
AFD,TTT
```

and assign a number for each row to it , which become this

```
A 1
B 1
AFD 2
DNGS 2
SGDH 2
NHYG 3
QHD 3
lkd 3
uyete 3   
AFD 4
TTT 4
```

How can I achieve this?

I am stuck in the following code:

```
import itertools
# open the data from the directory
with open ( './test.txt' ) as f:
    # Make a file named result to write your results there
    with open ( 'result.txt' , 'w' ) as w:
        # read each line with enumerate ( a number for each string)
        for n , line in enumerate ( f.readlines ( ) ):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following:

```
with open('test.txt') as f_in, open('result.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(s, i)
                          for i, l in enumerate(f_in, 1)
                          for s in l.strip().split(',')))
```

In above [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) will return `(index, line)` tuples from input file and indexes start from `1` which was passed as a parameter. Then for each line [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used to remove trailing newline and then line is [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) from every `,`. Finally the generator expression outputs strings with format `'word index'` that are joined together with newline character before being written to output file.

**Update** If you want to print the result instead of writing the file you can do so with following code:

```
with open('test.txt') as f_in:
    print '\n'.join('{} {}'.format(s, i)
                    for i, l in enumerate(f_in, 1)
                    for s in l.strip().split(','))
```

Output:

```
A 1
B 1
AFD 2
DNGS 2
SGDH 2
NHYG 3
QHD 3
lkd 3
uyete 3
AFD 4
TTT 4
```

Comment: I was just about to post my answer then I saw this, really neat!

Comment: @niemmi I get no error but also I get no output? would it be possible to show how to print the result also because your code is very complex and I cannot understand it :-)

Comment: @nik The output was written to a file with a same name as in your question. See the updated answer on how to print it and also for short explanation on what's happening.

Comment: @nik I tried with both versions in my answer and they worked as I expected them to. Did you try with exactly the same data that you posted and exactly the same code as in my answer with nothing added/changed/removed? Was `test.txt` in the same folder as the script?

Comment: @niemmi I liked and accepted your answer. There is something wrong with saving in Mac . When I save the xls file to txt , it adds `"`to it and also when I post it on GitHub your code works just fine but in my data it does not :-( however, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Include this at the top of your file, so you can use the `print` function (the `print` statement is deprecated in Python 3).

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then you should split the line based on `,`:

```
        for word in line.split(','):
            print(word, n+1, file=w)
```

Comment: I liked your answer thanks but `line`is giving error, i don't know what is wrong with my Mac or with my programming :-( it is making me crazy

Comment: @nik did you include the `from __future__` line at the top of your program? You can also use `print >> w, word, n+1`, but you should really start using the print **function** in all your programs, and in 2.7 can do so with that import. That has nothing to do with being on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example which showcases how to deal with splitting a string in Python (mind that this is written in Python 3, so you have to adapt it for Python 2.7):

```
arr = ("A,B","AFD,DNGS,SGDH","NHYG,QHD,lkd,uyete","AFD,TTT")
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    splitarr = arr[i].split(",")
    for splitItem in splitarr:
        print(splitItem + " " + str(i+1))
```

Comment: You can use `enumerate` instead of iterating over range and getting the value from array by index. Like this `for index, value in enumerate(arr)`.